# hapi.js Version 18.x Typings

Tags: node.js, typescript, hapi.js

I recently upgraded my project to use the `@hapi/hapi` node modules vs. the old `hapi` module.  I'm using version 18.3.1 (`"@hapi/hapi": "^18.3.1"`).

My Typescript definitions no longer work as the Import reads: `import * as Hapi from 'hapi';`

When running the node process I get the module not found error.  Is there a way to point the `@types/hapi` typings to the new `@hapi/hapi` module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uninstall the `@types/hapi` dependency. This didn't work for me moving to `18.3.1`. Instead install `@types/hapi__hapi`.  I searched for a while and ran across that package, which seems to do the trick.

```
npm un @types/hapi -D
npm i @types/hapi__hapi -D
```

Then instead of importing from `'hapi'`, import from `'@hapi/hapi'`.

```
import * as Hapi from '@hapi/hapi';
```

Comment: Thanks!  Nice find on the hapi__hapi typings

Comment: This also works for Joi: `npm i @types/hapi__joi -D`

Comment: Yes, for testing `@types/hapi__code` and `@types/hapi__lab`.  I'm glad you're going again.  I was stuck for a while ;-P

Comment: Anyone know WHY this is the case?

Comment: No clue.  I never found the reason why.

Comment: Got an answer: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/41536#issuecomment-574766548
Basically, `@types/hapi__hapi` is for the package name change to `@hapi/hapi` vs just `hapi`.
This is required because of the way typings work.